# Playwright tests fail without timeout or providing any error message

Tags: playwright

I'm testing my Stripe integration with Playwright. This is a part of the code for it

```
  await buyerPage.click('[data-testid="screenplay-side-modal-buy-screenplay"]')
  await buyerPage.waitForNavigation({ url: /^https:\/\/checkout.stripe.com\// })
  await buyerPage.click('[data-testid="hosted-payment-submit-button"]')
  await buyerPage.waitForURL(
    `${baseUrl}/screenplay/${authorScreenplayId}?success=true`,
    {
      timeout: 30000,
    }
  )
```

No matter what I do, 5 seconds after `hosted-payment-submit-button` is clicked, the whole test fails without an error.

But it's even crazier that this code repeat twice in the test, and first time it works without any issues.

What am I doing wrong? Also, is there a way to have a detailed message why the test failed in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

waitForNavigation is [deprecated](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-navigation) , use [waitForUrl](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-url) instead.

I would re-write it like below:

```
 await buyerPage.click('[data-testid="screenplay-side-modal-buy-screenplay"]')
  await buyerPage.waitForURL('**//checkout.stripe.com')
  //verify an page element which confirms page loaded completely like may be an grid or button on the bottom
  await buyerPage.click('[data-testid="hosted-payment-submit-button"]')
  await buyerPage.waitForURL(
    `${baseUrl}/screenplay/${authorScreenplayId}?success=true`,
    {
      timeout: 30000,
    }
  )
```